# Using Escape Button to exit jquery popup dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I managed to create a partial view with jquery for a popup dialog to show a create form, now my next problem is how to use the **Esc** key on the keyboard to return the page before the `pop-up`. I tried creating a close link/button and well it worked but I really like to use the the **Esc** key for practice.

Any idea about it?

Comment: did you code the dialog yourself, or use something like JQuery UI's dialog?

Comment: I created a new js file, then there I put the codes for my popup partial view (working) and hopefully for the escape key function

Comment: The standard jQuery.UI dialog already includes a `closeOnEscape` option.  Can you not use that?

Comment: @Corey yeah, i tried that but still nothing happens..

Comment: Add your Js and partial view code please.

Comment: @Shashank I have already done it, I tried implement the bundle for JqueryUI and it worked. There was nothing wrong with the answers. Thanks for the help, well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the keyup event and check the keycode. Make sure you add the selector.

```
keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 27) {
      // close your window
   }
});
```

Comment: I did it but nothing happens, I tried this:
`$(#dialog).keyup(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 27){
    $(#dialog).dialog("close");
    }
});`
Do I still lack something?, sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: Well, your selector should be in quotes.

$("#dialog")

Is this a javascript dialog or an actual browser popup? If you're using jQuery UI Dialogs, it should already support what you're trying to do.

Comment: I created my own js file for the partial view and hopefully for the escape key function.. does my js file still lacking something?

Answer (score 1):

You must set keyup event on the document and inside you should add the code for closing the dialog.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) 
  {
      $('#dialog').dialog('close'); 
  } 

});
```